# Values set in overridden OnActionExecuting is null in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have made a base controller class that overrides OnActionExecuting as follows:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string ActionName;
    public string ControllerName;

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ActionDescriptor    actionDescriptor    = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        string              ActionName          = actionDescriptor.ActionName;
        string              ControllerName      = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

In a controller i want to use these values

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index(int page)
    {
        if (ActionName == null)
            throw new Exception("ASP.NET MVC3 ABSURDLY GROTESQUE ERROR. CALL FOR REINFORCEMENTS! SERVER CORE ABOUT TO EXPLODE!!!");
            .
            .
            .
```

OnActionExecuting is called first and the values are set. However, my server core explodes every time when reaching the controller code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put `string` before those variables in the `OnActionExecuting` method or you are redeclaring new local variables and your fields stay null and unassigned:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string ActionName;
    public string ControllerName;

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        ActionName = actionDescriptor.ActionName;
        ControllerName = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And for better encapsulation use properties:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string ActionName { get; private set; };
    public string ControllerName { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        ActionName = actionDescriptor.ActionName;
        ControllerName = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn!!! Time to take a break. Embarrassing to say the least. No more copy paste errors tonight. I'm checking in...thanks.